# Join results using group by clause

Tags: sql, hive, subquery, inner-join, having-clause

How do i join the below 2 queries
Query 1

```
select phn,count(*) from table 1 
group by phn
having count(*)>20
```

with the above result i need to join table 2 to get ids

Query 2

```
select count(distinct id) from table 2 
where (result_of_query1).phn=table 2.phn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join as follows:

```
select count(distinct id)
from table2 t2
inner join (
    select phn
    from table1 
    group by phn
    having count(*) > 20 
) t1 on t1.phn = t2.phn
```

Comment: this is returning error "where returns BOOLEAN"

Comment: @Saras: are you getting the same error with the two queries I provided?

Comment: no only for the first, the second answer worked. Thanks :-)